# Why is the texture paint doing this?

Tags: texture-painting

Something has happened, this is texture paint mode. I already tried removing doubles, fixing normals...frustration supreme.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 2):

The part, which is purple, has different material applied then the rest of the dress.It's DiffuseMap.001 instead of DiffuseMap, they have different diffuse textures, so you can't paint both of them at the same time.

Comment: How can I merge it so it's all on one map?

Comment: You probably don't need few different materials assigned to this dress, as you are painting all of it by hand anyway, so just remove all materials except first.